# Access control in elastic search indices

Tags: elasticsearch, access-control, gravitee

I have an instance of elastic search running and I can see the list of indices by hitting the URL `http://165.30.5.62:9300/_cat/indices?v`

Now for a particular index I can see the data as `http://165.30.5.62:9300/{index}/_search?size=100&pretty=true` and it shows me different metrices

My question is that I want an access control on this data inside a specific index so not everyone can see what are the metrices present. How do i enable that in elastic search container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elasticsearch has built in access control mechanisms but only in [Platinum license](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elastic-stack-overview/current/authorization.html) and its available as a part of XPack features.

If you are not using platinum license, you may need to implement the access control yourself by creating an [Elastic Search plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/6.6/plugin-authors.html).